# Trying to find a 2020 puzzle hunt with a puzzle based on Among Us

Tags: logical-deduction, liars, puzzle-identification

I am trying to find a puzzle hunt that I believe was held in 2020. It contained a puzzle based on the game Among Us with 26 characters, and you had to decide who were the imposters. The imposters all told lies and the crewmates all told the truth, so it was similar to a knights/knaves puzzle. Anyone know where to find this puzzle?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Do you remember anything else about this puzzlehunt? Other puzzles, general design of the hunt's mechanisms, artwork, etc.? Please also take the [tour] when you have time.

Comment: I do not remember anything else sadly.

Comment: Is this actually a question or is a puzzle itself?

Comment: This is actually a question.

Comment: I think if you search it on Youtube some results will be given.